# Set Ansible fact based on symbolic link

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task to install Anaconda:

```
---
- name: "Set variables"
  set_fact:
    package: "/software/anaconda/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh"

- set_fact:
    anadir: "/opt/anaconda/anaconda3-2019.07"

- name: "Check existence"
  stat:
    path: "{{ anadir }}"
  register: anaconda

- debug:
    msg: "{{ anadir }} already exists."
  when: anaconda.stat.exists == True

- name: Install Anaconda
  shell: "/bin/bash {{ package }} -b -p {{ anadir }}"
  when: anaconda.stat.exists == False
```

But I don't want to have the version hardcoded in the file. I don't even want it in any kind of variable.

If I have a link in my directory `/software/anaconda` like `latest -> Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh` I am sure I can set a fact with the value `Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh`. But I could not find an elegant way to do it.

Comment: You are already using the `stat` module here. Use it on your `latest` link and explore the result. You will find what you need.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for! I can just use `lnk_source`, right?

Comment: Isn't it pointing to the file you are looking for ?

Comment: It is. Do you want to provide that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `stat` module against your `latest` link, register the result and explore it.

You should find a `lnk_source` key pointing to your original file.

Ref: [`stat` module return value specification](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#return-values)